# Model predicting constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am writing a tensorflow based deep learning linear regression algo to predict future stock prices. The problem I am currently facing is that the prediction remains constant throughout the entire learning process. I have tried different learning rates and I have more than enough data. How could I battle this problem?

```py
# model definition
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='linear', input_shape=(7,), kernel_regularizer='l2'),  # input shape required
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation="linear", kernel_regularizer='l2'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer='l2'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear", kernel_regularizer='l2')
])

# learning rate control
initial_learning_rate = 0.5
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=40000,
    decay_rate=0.05,
    staircase=True)

# loss calculation
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()

# model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule, clipnorm=1),
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: You should see if there's a signal before using a learning rate schedule, so remove the schedule and put the default value. Also, use `'relu'` for all hidden layer, or else your NN won't be able to make a non-linear function. Accuracy doesn't make sense here, remove it.

Comment: What about the data: did you scale it e.g to (0, 1)? It might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly your learning rate if you can't "learn" anything. Try as small as 1e-5 and come up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your regression problem, use `activation='linear'` in 3rd layer. Also your learning rate seems to be quite high. Use `1e^-4`